# Closed-form of an integral

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I came across the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin \theta \ d \theta}{(x-a \cos \theta)^2+(y-b \sin \theta)^2}$$
where $x,y$ are real variables independent of $\theta$ and $0<b<a$. Now I was wondering if it could be written in a closed-form. I have been trying a number of different things but nothing seems to be working. Is there anyone how knows if this is even possible at all? And if so, would you be so kind to help me in the right direction? Any hint that gets me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Intervals for $x,y,a,b$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: Inequalities between the variables would've been nicer. Still, I would try.

Comment: You say that x and y are real variables.  However, are they constant with respect to $\theta$?

Comment: If $x,y$ are constant with respect to $\theta$, then either the universal half-tangent substitution $t=\tan\frac12\theta$, or if you are happy with contour integral, $z=e^{i\theta}$, is a good place to start.

Comment: I have tried both of these things, in each case I get a fourth-degree polynomial in the denominator. Is there a general way to find the roots of such an equation?

Comment: This looks like an elliptic integral. I would be doubtful of finding a closed form

Comment: @K.defaoite What about an expression in terms of elliptic integrals? Is that something we can hope for? If so, that would be nice already.

Comment: You don't need elliptic integrals.  Integrating rational functions are easy with partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @user10354138. I was writing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claude expanded on the half-tangent case, so let me do the contour integral version.

Assuming $b^2x^2+a^2y^2\neq a^2b^2$ (and maybe $(x,y)\neq(\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2},0)$ too, for simplicity).  The substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{(x-a\cos\theta)^2+(y-b\sin\theta)^2}
&=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{\frac12(z^{-2}-1)\,\mathrm{d}z}{(x-\frac12a(z+z^{-1}))^2+(y-\frac1{2i}b(z-z^{-1}))^2}\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{2(1-z^2)\,\mathrm{d}z}{(2xz-a(z^2+1))^2+(2yz+ib(z^2-1))^2}\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\frac{2(1-z^2)\,\mathrm{d}z}{((a+b)z^2-2(x+iy)z+(a-b))((a-b)z^2-2(x-iy)z+(a+b))}
\end{align*}
The poles are at
$$\require{color}
z_{{\color{red}\pm},{\color{blue}\pm}}=\frac{w_{\color{red}\pm}{\color{blue}\pm}\sqrt{w_{\color{red}\pm}^2-a^2+b^2}}{a{\color{red}\pm}b},\quad w_{\pm}=x\pm iy
$$
and you should be able to work out the residues and whether $z$ lies inside/on/outside the unit circle.  If you have assumed $(x,y)\neq(\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2},0)$, we have four simple poles.  Hence
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{(x-a\cos\theta)^2+(y-b\sin\theta)^2}=2\pi i\sum_{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in\{\pm\}} \frac{1_{\lvert z_{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2}\rvert\leq1}+1_{\lvert z_{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2}\rvert<1}}{2}\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2}}f
$$
where $f(z)=\frac{2(1-z^2)}{((a+b)z^2-2(x+iy)z+(a-b))((a-b)z^2-2(x-iy)z+(a+b))}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How did you find the factorization of the polynomial in the denominator into two second-degree polynomials? Also, shouldn't there be a factor of $(a {\color{red}\pm} b)^{-1}$ at the poles?

Comment: (1) The sum of two squares factors over $\mathbb{C}$.  (2) Yes, that factor should be there, correcting.

Comment: Right, of course! How about the sum of three squares? Is there anything I can do with that?

Answer (score 3):

Using the tangent half-angle subsitution, the antiderivative to be computed is
$$\frac{4}{a^2+2 a x+x^2+y^2}\int \frac t {t^4+\alpha t^3+\beta t^2+\alpha t+\gamma} \,dt$$ with
$$\alpha=-\frac{4 b y}{a^2+2 a x+x^2+y^2}\qquad  \qquad \beta=   \frac{-2 a^2+4 b^2+2 x^2+2 y^2}{a^2+2 a x+x^2+y^2}$$
$$\gamma=\frac{a^2-2 a x+x^2+y^2}{a^2+2 a x+x^2+y^2}$$

Now, let $(p,q,r,s)$ be the roots of the quartic equation
$$J=\int \frac t {t^4+\alpha t^3+\beta t^2+\alpha t+\gamma} \,dt=\int \frac t {(t-p)(t-q)(t-r)(t-s)} \,dt$$ and use partial fraction decomposition and you will face
$$J=\int\frac P{t-p}\,dt+\int\frac Q{t-q}\,dt+\int\frac R{t-r}\,dt+\int\frac S{t-s}\,dt$$ which is simple.

By the way, split the interval of integration if you do not want to obtain $0$ as the result.